# Virtualbox networking for development, connecting from the host, and local network

Tags: virtualbox

I've got an Ubuntu Virtualbox (v4.02) VM setup (running on a Windows 7 host), with SSH and Apache working on a static IP address (192.168.1.x) - but the VM itself can't talk to the outside world. I can ping addresses. but can't retrieve webpages, or talk to external DBs or a subversion repository from within the VM.

At home, I connect on a local network from another machine (by ssh, Samba and web). At the office, I just do the same into my VM from the same laptop. I can SSH to the VM from the laptop, or desktop -

I'm trying to get a single configuration where I can use the server - and have it able to talk to the outside world - by ethernet (at home), or by Wifi.

I have two bridged adaptors setup:
1/ to the wifi, address by dhcp 
2/ to ethernet adaptor, and is set as a static IP in the vm

When I do an `mtr yahoo.com` (like traceroute), it shows my router, but beyond that, just shows '???', and stops at hop 2. I can traceroute to my desktop, from the VM on my laptop though.

Comment: What kind of networking adapter have you got configured?  "Host Only", "Bridged" or "NAT"?

Comment: I've fixed the problem of being able to get out from the VM to the rest of the internetnet - a `route` command showed two gateways listed, one per eth port. Removing both, then adding the wired network back in, enabled it. I don't know how it would fare if running only on wifi however. That is still the crux of the question.